# Restriction for having maximum number of Streams in a single Procedure file

Tags: stream, max, progress-4gl, openedge

I would like to know whether we have restrictions for having maximum number of streams in a single procedure file.

If so please provide them with Progress version number

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Ravi

Comment: What Progress version are *you* using?

Answer (score 1):

There's a maximum of 50 defined streams per procedure (in OE 11.5).

Same in [10.2B](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge102b/pdfs/dp4gl/dp4gl.pdf).

[Version 6 (truly ancient) has a limit of 5 named streams.](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P94453)